# Wordpress mobile integration?

Tags: mobile, wordpress, smartphone

I have an existing website that works with my custom theme.   Unfortunately, it does not appear too well when I access it from my smart phone.

Can someone suggest a good plugin that will help with the user experience from a smart phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bravenewcode.com/store/plugins/wptouch-pro/

Let me know if you like it...

Comment: I looked around and tried a few.  This happened to be the best one out there.  Over 3,000,000 downloads!  Thank you.